# how to merge two array list in JSON and view in data table rows using asp.net MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

`text` and `EmpList` having two arraylist how to return two array list in JSON and how to view in data table rows in a single view .i have split the code two `$.each(data.EmpList, function (i, item)` and `$.each(data.test, function (i, item)` condition how to merge both array values in a single Row view..

```
$("#DomainID").change(function () {

                var id = $(this).val();
                $("#example tbody tr").remove();

                $.ajax({

                    type: 'POST',

                    url: '@Url.Action("ViewModules")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { id: id },
                    success: function (data) {
                        var items = '';
                        $.each(data.EmpList, function (i, item) {
                            $("#findValue").show();
                            var rows = "<tr>"

                            + "<td>" + item.ModuleName + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item.Url + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item.RoleName  + "</td>"
                            + "</tr>";
                            $('#example tbody').append(rows);
                        });

                        $.each(data.test, function (i, item) {
                            $("#findValue").show();
                            var rows = "<tr>"
                            + "<td>" + item.RoleName + "</td>"
                            + "</tr>";
                            $('#example tbody').append(rows);
                        });

                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                        var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                        alert("Message: " + r.Message);
                        alert("StackTrace: " + r.StackTrace);
                        alert("ExceptionType: " + r.ExceptionType);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            })
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ViewModules(int id)
        {
            Domain_Bind();
            dynamic mymodel = new ExpandoObject();
            userType type = new userType();
            List<ViewRoleModules> EmpList = type.GetRoleModulesViews(id);
            string sRptModuleIDs = string.Empty;
            foreach (ViewRoleModules emp in EmpList)
            {
                sRptModuleIDs += emp.ModuleID + ",";
            }
            if (sRptModuleIDs != "")
            {
                sRptModuleIDs = sRptModuleIDs.Remove(sRptModuleIDs.Length - 1, 1);
            }

            List<ViewRoleModules> RoleList;
            List<ViewRoleModules> test = new List<ViewRoleModules>();
            foreach (var rid in sRptModuleIDs.Split(','))
            {
                string RID = rid;
                RoleList = type.GetSiteRoleModulesViews(rid);
                foreach (ViewRoleModules vip in RoleList)
                {
                    test.Add(new ViewRoleModules {
                        RoleName = vip.RoleName
                    });
                }
            }

            var data = new { EmpList = EmpList, test = test };

            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Here my ouptput screen:

[image: output]

```
public class ViewRoleModules
    {
        [Key]
        public int ModuleID { get; set; }
        public int DomainID { get; set; }
        public int ParentModuleID { get; set; }
        public int CompanyTypeID { get; set; }
        public string ModuleName { get; set; }
        public string FolderName { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public int TabOrder { get; set; }
        public string Style { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string IsTab { get; set; }
        public string ApprovalProcess { get; set; }
        public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public int RoleID { get; set; }

    }
```

And

```
public List<ViewRoleModules> GetRoleModulesViews(int id)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Admin"].ConnectionString))
            {
                List<ViewRoleModules> EmpList = new List<ViewRoleModules>();
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("MEDEIL_Modules_SelectDomainModules", conn);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DomainID", id);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                conn.Open();
                da.Fill(dt);
                conn.Close();
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {

                    EmpList.Add(

                        new ViewRoleModules
                        {
                            ModuleID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ModuleID"]),
                            CompanyTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CompanyTypeID"]),
                            DomainID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["DomainID"]),
                            ParentModuleID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ParentModuleID"]),
                            ModuleName = Convert.ToString(dr["ModuleName"]),
                            FolderName = Convert.ToString(dr["FolderName"] == DBNull.Value ? null : dr["FolderName"].ToString()),
                            Url = Convert.ToString(dr["Url"]),
                            TabOrder = Convert.ToInt32(dr["TabOrder"]),
                            Style = Convert.ToString(dr["Style"]),
                            Status = Convert.ToString(dr["Status"]),
                            IsTab = Convert.ToString(dr["IsTab"]),
                            ApprovalProcess = Convert.ToString(dr["ApprovalProcess"]),
                            CreatedBy = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CreatedBy"] == DBNull.Value ? null : dr["CreatedBy"].ToString()),
                            CreatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["CreatedDate"]),
                            ModifiedBy = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ModifiedBy"] == DBNull.Value ? null : dr["ModifiedBy"].ToString()),
                            ModifiedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ModifiedDate"] == DBNull.Value ? null : dr["ModifiedDate"].ToString())
                        }
                    );
                }

                return EmpList;
            }
        }


        public List<ViewRoleModules> GetSiteRoleModulesViews(string rid)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Admin"].ConnectionString))
            {
                List<ViewRoleModules> RoleList = new List<ViewRoleModules>();
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("MEDEIL_SiteRoleModules_SelectOne", conn);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModuleID", Convert.ToInt32(rid));
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                conn.Open();
                da.Fill(dt);
                conn.Close();
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {

                    RoleList.Add(

                        new ViewRoleModules
                        {
                            //RoleID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["RoleID"]),
                            RoleName = Convert.ToString(dr["RoleName"])

                        }
                    );
                }

                return RoleList;
            }
        }
```

Comment: are you able to recieve emplist and test in javascript success ?

Comment: yes sir Role rows fetch in the bottom of the table i want to fetch the row in the relevant ID column

Comment: @vishalsharma yes i want to recieve emplist and test in javascript success

Comment: hit breakpoint in success callback and see whats coming in data?

Comment: @vishalsharma https://i.stack.imgur.com/COwdc.png  see

Comment: i have change the text name to Role don't confuse @vishalsharma

Comment: not there,  in javascript success , see how to debug js in browser if in case you dont know

Comment: @vishalsharma  https://ibb.co/h0sFZb  See output
https://ibb.co/kpr9ub

Comment: if I'm not wrong, the employee and role have to be properties of a model class(say X) and list of that model X has to sent as the result.

Comment: @IvinRaj Can you edit the question and provide details about `ViewRoleModules` class.

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas check it my updated code

Comment: @lvinRaj Here one module can have multiple roles? Am I correct?

Comment: yes you are correct sir @Kumar_Vikas

Comment: @lvinRaj Is there any issue if you create a separate model class for the `role` and in `ViewRoleModules` create a List<> of that class.

Comment: No sir for my understanding i have to split the function @Kumar_Vikas

Comment: any idea @Kumar_Vikas

Comment: @IvinRaj I have answered. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current scenario that you are working on, where each module can have multiple roles.`EmpList` and `test` are returned as result. Here I have used `ModuleId` as a common value for linking two lists.

**C#:**

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult ViewModules(int id)
        {
            Domain_Bind();
            dynamic mymodel = new ExpandoObject();
            userType type = new userType();


            List<ViewRoleModules> EmpList = type.GetRoleModulesViews(id);

            List<ViewRoleModules> RoleList;
            List<ViewRoleModules> test = new List<ViewRoleModules>();
            foreach (ViewRoleModules emp in EmpList)
            {
                RoleList = type.GetSiteRoleModulesViews(emp.ModuleId);
                foreach (ViewRoleModules vip in RoleList)
                {
                    test.Add(new ViewRoleModules
                    {
                        RoleName = vip.RoleName,
                        ModuleId = vip.ModuleId
                    });
                }
            }

            var data = new { EmpList = EmpList, test = test };

            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Change made to class `GetSiteRoleModulesViews`, added `ModuleId`.

```
public List<ViewRoleModules> GetSiteRoleModulesViews(int _ModuleId)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Admin"].ConnectionString))
            {
                List<ViewRoleModules> RoleList = new List<ViewRoleModules>();
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("MEDEIL_SiteRoleModules_SelectOne", conn);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModuleID", _ModuleId);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                conn.Open();
                da.Fill(dt);
                conn.Close();
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {

                    RoleList.Add(

                        new ViewRoleModules
                        {
                            //RoleID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["RoleID"]),
                            RoleName = Convert.ToString(dr["RoleName"])
                            //*****Included ModuleID Here*****
                            ModuleId = _ModuleId;
                        }
                    );
                }

                return RoleList;
            }
        }
```

**JS:**

```
$("#DomainID").change(function () {

                var id = $(this).val();
                $("#example tbody tr").remove();

                $.ajax({

                    type: 'POST',

                    url: '@Url.Action("ViewModules")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { id: id },
                    success: function (data) {
                        var items = '';
                        $.each(data.EmpList, function (i, item) {
                            $("#findValue").show();

                            /*Find Role here - Comparing Emp List ModuleId to RoleList ModuleId*/

                            var Result = $(data.test).filter(function (index, element) {
                                return element.ModuleId == item.ModuleId
                            });

                            var rows = "<tr>"
                            + "<td>" + item.ModuleName + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item.Url + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + Result.RoleName + "</td>"
                            + "</tr>";
                            $('#example tbody').append(rows);
                        });

                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                        var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                        alert("Message: " + r.Message);
                        alert("StackTrace: " + r.StackTrace);
                        alert("ExceptionType: " + r.ExceptionType);
                    }
                });
                return false;
    });
```

Comment: Assuming you can rectify those issues.

Comment: @IvinRaj Updated the answer. Please check. Updated the parameter of `GetSiteRoleModulesViews`  from string to int.

Comment: can you slove my problem above iamge

Comment: @IvinRaj I have updated the answer. Do debug and check whether the moduleID is properly assigned or not, since that is the common comparing value between the two lists.